# How to determine location of wrapper (relative to module - and not theme folder) in placement info file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, orchardcms

i am trying to specify a `cshtml` file as wrapper for specific `ContentType` in a `placementinfo` file.

my definition looks like this :

```
  <Place Parts_Estate="Content:4;Wrapper=OrderResultItemWrapper"/>
```

now the problem is that , when i investigate the contentItem in ShapeTracing window i figured out that the search location for Wrapper view file is theme folder.

```
 ~/Themes/EmlakTheme/Views/OrderResultItemWrapper.cshtml
```

anyone have any idea how to convince the view engine to search within module folder rather than theme folder.

any help is very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

my problem is as follow :

1 - i have placed a cshtml file as a wrapper in the module's directory.

2 - i haven't placed any copy of (and not any other file with this name) in the theme folder

3 - the wrapper doesn't affect my shape.

4 - when i searched for problem i found out that shape tracing window showing the

```
"~/Themes/EmlakTheme/Views/OrderResultItemWrapper.cshtml"
```

path.that means it doesn't search the modules directory for my wrapper file and results in not displaying the wrapper.

**EDIT**

My problem have been solved.
my mistake was adding wrapper to `DisplayTemplate` directory.i have placed it in Views (root) directory and now it is working well.**thanks all guys participating in answer**.

Comment: i can put it there.but i want it to be built-in for module!

Comment: Right, I said do *not* have one in the theme.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy thanks for your response.i misunderstood you.i thought you are asking me question!but i haven't placed any wrapper in theme folder.

Comment: What's your question then? The view engine looks in *dozens* of places. Are you complaining that it looks in the theme? How is that a problem if it finds nothing there?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili Can you confirm that the wrapper is being rendered at all? If it is that would mean a possible bug (wrong URL is displayed) within Shape Tracing module.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili Could you please clarify what the real problem actually is? Is it about that URL being incorrectly displayed or about the wrapper not being rendered?

Comment: thank you all.i edited my post to better explain my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same cshtml file in both a module and a theme, the latter will take precedence. If you need to use the one provided by module - delete the one from the theme.

Comment: the theme folder dose not contains the wrapper file.the only place i have the wrapper is the module directory.